# Is it safe to cook chicken soup if the water doesn't quite cover it?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, soup

So, being dumb, I got my chicken all thawed out before I remembered that my friend still has my soup pot. I got the chicken crammed into a smaller pot, but I can't get the water to quite cover it. I hoped it would cook down enough for the water to cover it, and it did cook down a little bit, but there is still a teeny bit above the water. I took a picture of it:

http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/2629/img0053qm.jpg

Should I be ok with that? Maybe cook it a bit longer? I'd hate to throw it out but heck I don't want Salmonella.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be fine.  As the chicken softens, and with a bit of a stir, it will all get cooked.  the steam and conductive heat will cook and keep safe even the minuscule portion above the water line.

Comment: I'll add that if @Aurast is paranoid, taking the temperature with a food thermometer ought to remove all doubt. I suspect it'll be well over 160°F.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ do you sleep? ; )

Comment: @ferdiesfoodlab Not as much as I would like, no.  And SA is one of the things I do when cannot.

Comment: Well, I ate it, and it was good :) Crossing my fingers that I'm still thinking that in a few days! But it's true, I'm paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you put a lit on - it will cook. It will basically steam the exposed chicken!!